# Keep Array of Week Days Always Ordered When Removing or Adding Days

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep an array updated by week days order

for example: `var weekDays = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"];`

Now I have another new array where I have button to add different week days of the week like

```
var newArry = [];
newArry.push("Fri");
newArry.push("Mon");
newArry.push("Sat");
newArry.splice(1, 1); //remove a day example
```

Now you can see the output will be random order something like `['Fri', 'Mon', 'Sat']` I want to keep the order of the array like the origial `weekDays` if to convert it to number 0-6 always have it in order from 0-1-2-3-4-5-6

I thought on using the following `_.indexOf(weekDays, day), 0, day` but it still has broken cases sometimes, My head really hurts trying to perfect this.

Comment: Are you guaranteed something pushed to `newArray` will be a item equal to an item in `weekDay`?

Comment: @PaulS. Yes it's based on button click with a week day value such as "Mon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to end up with a sparse array, you can define your own sorting function and simply resort the array after any additions. Like so:

```
function sortByDay(a,b) {
  var order = {
    Mon: 0,
    Tue: 1,
    Wed: 2,
    Thu: 3,
    Fri: 4,
    Sat: 5,
    Sun: 6
  };
  return order[a] - order[b];
}

var arr = ['Fri', 'Mon', 'Sat'];
arr.sort(sortByDay);
// ['Mon', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
```

Comment: simple and perfect thanks going to learn this code why something like this couldn't pop into my head whats wrong with me :)

Comment: @BorisDaka Nothings wrong with you, just need more practice. Many things seem obvious once we know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation and just drop the item in straight where it should be, use `delete` to remove it

```
var newArray = [];

// adding an item to newArray
newArray[weekDays.indexOf(item)] = item;

// removing an item from newArray
delete newArray[idx];
// or
delete newArray[weekDays.indexOf(item)]
```

So for example if you're adding `"Wed"`

```
newArray[weekDays.indexOf('Wed')] = 'Wed';
newArray; // [undefined × 2, "Wed"]
```

If you expect to be doing this a lot you can speed this up a little if you write a dictionary,

```
var d = {};
weekDays.forEach(function (e, i) {d[e] = i;});
```

Now it's just an object loopup

```
newArray[d[item]] = item;
delete newArray[d[item]];
```

Comment: what about the undefined array x2 I don't need an empty undefined array so if it's 2 days but the index is 3 and 2 is empty let it be 2 now it's more complicated but that how I need it, I gotta use the array later